# How to deselect others when select one in Backbone view?

Tags: backbone.js

It's an easy example as following:

There are many avatars and only one avatar can be selected each time.

I have a model 'Avatar', collection 'Avatars' and model's view 'AvatarView'.
Also there is a view named 'AvatarAppView' which is responsible to render the app view.

My implementation is as following:

When one avatar is selected, click event is trigged in the model's view 'AvatarView', then it will be selected but cannot make other models unselected.

Are there any nice solutions? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Backbone views have [`Backbone.Events`](http://backbonejs.org/#Events) mixed in so views can produce their own events and other views can listen for those events. So your `AvatarView` can trigger an event when it is selected:

```
select: function() {
    // Mark this avatar as selected...
    this.trigger('selected', this);
},
unselect: function() {
    // Undo the "mark this avatar as selected" from above.
}
```

and then the `AvatarAppView` can listen for those events:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'selected');
    //...
},
render: function() {
    this.kids = [ ];
    this.collection.each(function(m) {
        var v = new AvatarView({ model: m });
        v.on('selected', this.selected);
        this.kids.push(v);
        this.$el.append(v.render().el);
    }, this);
    return this;
}
```

Then a simple `selected` event handler for `AvatarAppView` to unselect the other `AvatarView`s:

```
selected: function(v) {
    _.chain(this.kids).reject(function(k) { return k == v }).invoke('unselect');
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/thRHK/

Comment: I split avatarView and avatarAppView into two files, and this.trigger('selected', this); cannot trigger the 'selected' event in avatarAppView.

Comment: @goofansu: But it worked when they were in the same file? What happens when the event is triggered?

Comment: That's my fault, I've found the problem which is a 'this' reference error. Your answer is wonderful.